# WIF SAML 2.0 CTP Identity Provider Initiated SSO

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, saml-2.0

I am developing a single sign on ASP.NET application, and I am trying to decide whether to make use of the WIF SAML 2.0 CTP or instead use ADFS 2.0. I have read several places that the WIF SAML 2.0 CTP enables identity provider initiated SSO, but I can't find any examples or tutorials anywhere. Does anyone know a good resource for becoming familiar with the methods of doing this using WIF CTP?

Comment: What is so important in idp initiated sso? What are your requirements?

Comment: Because I am working with a 3rd party that has a portal website that uses links to post SAML responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want SSO from your ASP.NET application to a SAML IdP?

It sounds like you've figured out that you can either go direct to the SAML IdP by adding a SAML stack to your application or by going WS-Fed to ADFS and then SAML to the IdP.

As mentioned the SAML CTP has been in CTP for ages and there is little documentation.

Have a look at the [OpenSSO Fedlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/confignetsp.htm).

However, you will probably find the ADFS option both quicker and easier.

Answer (score 1):

The SAML2 CTP is pre-release and I am really sceptical that this will ever RTM. So I wouldn't use it.